# From self adjoint, positive semi definite operator to square root?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

If we have an operator $T:V\to V$ where $V$ is finite-dimensional.

And, it is self-adjoint and positive semi-definite. we have to prove that $T$ has a square root.

I need help with the starting approach to this problem.

To me, I guess, I should start with the spectral theorem. But, then what should I do? I want some hints to solve it.

Comment: You're on the right track, you must use the Spectral Theorem. Use it to reduce the problem to diagonal matrices. Can you find a square root for a diagonal matrix associated to a positive definite transformation?

Comment: Umm, I am shooting in the dark. Is it just the square root of the entries?

Comment: In the diagonal case, it is! Now, use the Spectral Theorem to complete the argument.

Comment: Thank you. and, is there a alternative way to solve it ? I would like to explore that too.

Comment: I don't know of any other alternative ways, but surely there could be. If you're interested, try to look up the Square Root Theorem for positive definite matrices (it's a refined statement for your question but assuming the your matrix is nonsingular).

Comment: Thank you. I will look it up.