# Show $S^2 = T$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

Let $(V, ⟨, ⟩)$ be a real inner product space.
Let a self-adjoint transformation $T : V → V$ be positive definite, that is $⟨Tv,v⟩ > 0$ for all $v \ne 0$.
I have shown that all eigenvalues of T are positive. How can I show that there is a positive definite self-adjoint $S:V →V$ with $S^2 =T$?

Comment: See the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4211825/from-self-adjoint-positive-semi-definite-operator-to-square-root).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A doubt in the proof that there square root of a positive self-adjoint operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813145/a-doubt-in-the-proof-that-there-square-root-of-a-positive-self-adjoint-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Laplace transform
\begin{align}
     \mathscr{L}\{t^{-1/2}\}(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}t^{-1/2}dt&=\sqrt{\pi}s^{-1/2} \\
 \frac{s}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}t^{-1/2}dt&=s^{1/2} \\
  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-st}-1)t^{-1/2}dt&=s^{1/2} \\
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty(e^{-st}-1)(-1/2)t^{-3/2}dt&=\sqrt{s} \\
  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-st})t^{-3/2}dt&=\sqrt{s}
\end{align}
So, one way to define $S=\sqrt{T}$ is by using the $C_0$ semigroup:
$$
       \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-tT)})t^{-3/2}dt = \sqrt{T}
$$
This definition makes it easier to show that $\sqrt{T} \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** try to take the (positive) square root of the eigenvalues.

- What do they represent?
- How can you use them to construct $S$?

**Second hint:** Try diagonalizing $T$. What do you get?

Comment: I noticed that since T is self adjoint, there is a basis consisting of its eigenvectors, so T would be diagonal and S would also be diagonal and its entries the square roots of the eigenvalues. But how do I show S is self-adjoint?

Comment: Try to construct $S$ explicitly, it might help you.

Comment: Well, S is diagonal and its entries are the square roots of the eigenvalues of T, but I don't see why it would be self-adjoint

Comment: If $T=\Sigma D \Sigma^{-1}$ where $\Sigma$ is self-adjoint, then $S= \Sigma \sqrt{D} \Sigma^{-1}$ and since $\sqrt{D}$ is a diagonal real matrix then $\sqrt{D}^*=\sqrt{D}$. Use the fact that $S$ is a multiplication of $3$ self-adjoint matrices now.

Comment: Are we assuming finite dimensional?